# Button click event not firing for certain files in FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, file-upload

I have an aspx page with FileUpload Control. I select a file in it through given Browse button. On click of another button beneath it ("AddFile" : Text on button) file path from FileUpload control gets saved in database.

I am facing a weird scenario where click event of button "AddFile" is not firing for certain files selected in FileUpload control. When such files are selected and button is clicked, it gives I.E. 'Page cannot be displayed' and doesn't hits even the break point at click event.

Among the files for which it is happening, couple of them are CSV files with lakhs of records.

Below is the code I have for click event. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

```
protected void btnAddFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResults.Visible = false;

        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "" && ddlfiles.SelectedValue != "Select File")
        {
            List<string> ddValues = new List<string>();

            fName = ddlfiles.SelectedValue;

            DataInsertIntoSourceInfo(fName, FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            SelectFromSourceInfo();

            if (ViewState["ddValues"] != null)
            {
                ddValues = (List<string>)ViewState["ddValues"];
                ddValues.Add(fName);
                ViewState.Add("ddValues", ddValues);
            }

            else
            {
                ddValues.Add(fName);
                ViewState.Add("ddValues", ddValues);
            }

            ddlfiles.Items.Remove(fName);

            if (ddlfiles.Items.Count < 2)
            {
                btnAddFile.Enabled = false;
            }

            btnpkg.Visible = true;

        }

     else
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Select an appropriate File and assign Source", "ALERT");

         }
    }
```

Comment: It may be that some of the files you are uploading are too large, see the following page for more info : http://forums.asp.net/t/1636184.aspx

Comment: Added this to Web.Config : <system.web>
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>

Answer (score 0):

add this to your web config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="31457280" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please read the comments to the question, this issue was solved over a year ago.